# Adobeflash Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript

Good day! Where I can download

> Adobeflash Actionscript 3.0

it must be Adobe. i tried to Google but the results are not Adobe.

Comment: Did you try the real Adobe site?... y'know **adobe.com** and search for **Flash**?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to search...

> download adobe flash software

and what you are looking for was the first link in both : **[Google](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=dowload+adobe+flash+software&btnK=Google+Search#q=download+adobe+flash+software)** and **[Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=download%20adobe%20flash%20software&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=download%20adobe%20flash%20software&sc=2-28&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=9871E4A87B33434CBAF100EE6BC2901A)** search results. They promote animation features but of-course you can also write  Actionscript 3.0 code and that will compile it into an SWF or some app file for you.

Get **[Flash CC](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html)** here or look for older versions like Flash CS 5.5 or Flash CS 6 (older versions install on your computer. Flash CC is run from web & needs internet connection to work)